# How to extract readable values from .grib2

Tags: grib, cdo-climate

I have installed wgrib2 and degrib but cannot figure out how to extract values (human readable) for a specifig lat/lng.

```
degrib multi_1.nww3.t00z.grib2 -P -pnt -33.883,18.254
```

gives me:

```
SWPER, [s], 201403290000, 201403300900, 9999.000
WVDIR, [Degree true], 201403290000, 201403300900, 9999.000
SWDIR, [Degree true], 201403290000, 201403300900, 9999.000
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone wants to do this and they don't have degrib and wgrib2 installed, you can extract a point directly with **cdo** and output to a netcdf file:

```
cdo -f nc remapnn,lon=18.254/lat=-33.883 in.grb out.nc
```

"remapnn" means nearest neighbour remapping and this thus extracts the nearest gridpoint to the desired lon/lat without interpolation. You can then examine those values with

```
ncdump out.nc
```

Answer (score 0):

ok. i found the "mistake": the command ist correct and works if there is data for the given point. 9999.000 is the output if there is no data for the given point.. maybe it helps someone

Comment: If you use `-nMissing` it will drop all records with missing values.